# How do you sending ISO codes to payment processor?

Tags: php, iso, payment-processing

How can I send ISO codes to our payment processor?  Right now the province field is a free text box.  I would like to switch it to this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RmvJ4/

```
Select Country:
 <select onchange="print_state('state',this.selectedIndex);" id="country" name = "country"></select> <br />
 City/District/State:
 <select name ="state" id = "state"></select>

print_country("country");
$('#country').val('Indonesia');
print_state('state',$('#country')[0].selectedIndex);
```

However my developer has told me that this will not send the ISO codes.  I don't see where the ISO codes can be inserted.

The website that this will be used in can be found here:

```
http://206.130.189.117/cww/
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need, just drop the flag data.

[Download](http://stefangabos.ro/other-projects/list-of-world-countries-with-national-flags/)